# How to bind other form data arguments to Map in Class?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have method in `Spring RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mapping", method = { RequestMethod.POST }, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity fileQuery(MyRequest request) {}
```

And a class, `MyRequest`:

```
public class MyRequest{
    private String url;
    private String method;
    private String body;
    private MultipartFile file;
    // I have tried with MultiValueMap and no result
    private Map<String,String> formData;
    //getters and setters here
}
```

I want to create a method that accepts multipart / form-data requests with the following known arguments:

1. URL,
2. Method,
3. Body,
4. File,
5. Other `String:String` type arguments.

My solution is not working. Map is `null` in this case. How can I achieve something like this?

For better understanding I attached a screenshot from postman:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: why can't you pass it as part of the body

Comment: Instead of binding request parameters to a custom class, use `MultipartHttpServletRequest request` object and get parameters as `request.getParameterMap()`

Comment: @pvpkiran Because body is something completely different in this case. I'm doing proxy for another application that requires this kind of form-data.

Comment: @KedarJoshi Yes, your solution works but I'm still curious if is it possible to achieve it using binding to a custom class.

Comment: If you are using Jackson, then technically it is possible by using `@JsonAnySetter` and `@JsonAnyGetter`, but I can't be certain. See [this](https://layer4.fr/blog/2013/08/19/how-to-map-unknown-json-properties-with-jackson/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488644/json-to-hashmap-jackson)